# Making tops from arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string, integer

I have got two arrays, first contains some nicknames, and second contains integer values. Like `"felenot", "argold", "pilina"` and `130, 10, 66`.

I need to put numbers in descending order, and then make string like this: `felenot - 130`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I bet you also have to sort the nicknames ?

Comment: Please share the code you've tried with the specific error/problem you are experiencing. If you don't know where to start, http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php  will help with the sorting. Are both arrays he same size? How will you decide which number each nickname gets paired with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array_multisort

```
<?
$arr1 = ["felenot", "argold", "pilina"];
$arr2 = [130, 10, 66];

array_multisort($arr2, SORT_DESC, $arr1);

echo "{$arr1[0]} - {$arr2[0]}";
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/929164)

Comment: Does this puts nicks in decreasing order too?

Comment: it sorts both arrays synchronously